# Redirecionar URL no NodeJs

Tags: node.js, api, servidor, restful

Estou tentando redirecionar o meu login para um novo site após a função de validação do usuário. Após o redirecionamento a url no browse fica a partir da url onde estava o login:
http://localhost:2879/"https://web-stage.voxy.com/u/?auth_token=OLz8PxJY,
deveria ser apenas essa parte: https://web-stage.voxy.com/u/?auth_token=OLz8PxJY

```
    request('http://54.93.154.122:2801/'+doc.voxyid, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
    //console.log(error)
    res.redirect(JSON.stringify(body))
```

Answer (score 1):

Pessoal descobri o problema:
res.redirect(JSON.stringify(body))

Reescrita: res.redirect(body), dessa forma funcionou!